# Understanding Javascript PubSub

Tags: javascript, jquery, publish-subscribe

I'm trying to understand PubSub with a very simple example. In my fiddle, I have a simple input element. How do I keep my model.prop updated with the value of the input field?
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/amitava82/CHvFk/3/)

```
<button>update</button>
<input type="text" value="10" /> <br />
<label></label>​

var model = function(){
    var p1 = $('input').val();
    return {
        prop: p1             
    }        
}();

$('button').click(function(){
    $('label').text(model.prop)      
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(function(){

    var model = function(){
        return {
            prop: function () {
                return $('input').val();
            }                
        }        
    }();

    $('button').click(function(){
        $('label').text(model.prop)      
    })


})​
```

This works because instead of defining a scalar value for the `prop` property, you define a function and get that result. As such each time you call the property it is dynamically updated with the value in the text field. See http://jsfiddle.net/CHvFk/4/.
​

Comment: What's the reason for that IEFE around the model?

Comment: @Bergi Don't know -- he wrote it that way so I left it assuming there was a reason.

Comment: @LeviBotelho: I'd say you changed it in a way that makes it useless now.

Comment: @Bergi well are you going to explain why or wait for me to ask you why?

Comment: @Bergi - I assume that the automatic invoking was simply to create an object and that this could have been done with object literal syntax. I don't think that he was trying to define a constructor for an object type.

Comment: @LeviBotelho That's correct. It's a part of revealing pattern module I was learning.

Comment: @LeviBotelho: No, he did (try to) create a closure over `p1`. See my answer for that.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is an example for the Pub/Sub-pattern, but check this snippet:

```
var model = (function() {
    var inp = $('input');
    return {
        getProp: function() {
           return inp.val();
        }
    };
})();

$('button').click(function(){
    $('label').text(model.getProp());
});
```